# to create table used operator name but right syntax is required

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
[Item Type] VARCHAR(30) NULL,
[Sales Channel] VARCHAR(30) NULL,
[Order Priority] VARCHAR(30) NULL,
[Order Date] DATE NULL,
[Order ID] DECIMAL NULL,
[Ship Date] DATE NULL
)
```

Dear guys, please with how to use as right syntax for the table columns: e.g. Item Type - here "type" already existing in mysql, Sales Channel - here "channel" already exists in mysql as operator names. but i need to use as column names for the table. Thanks!

Comment: the same is happening with other names: order priority - "order", etc. the message is showing to use right syntaxes

Comment: is this mysql or sql server? you are surrounding your column names with square brackets ( [ ] ), mysql uses backticks ( ` ) to surround names. If you truly are using mysql then the answer would be to replace your square brackets with backticks (it's the character on the same key as the tilde ( ~ )).

Comment: another comment, if you can avoid using reserved keywords for column names I strongly suggest doing that. you avoid any possibility of problems downstream.

Comment: mysql, sir. it should be ([]) or just []

Comment: anyway, it is not working with either... red x icon appearing..

Comment: just to clarify for anyone looking for answers here, square brackets are not a valid option in mysql for this use case regardless of what OP says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to do this.

1. You could use double quotes (") to escape the reserved keyword.
2. You could use back-ticks (`)
3. You could prepend with schema name (only for tables) e.g.
   myschema.Table.

A good reference is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: the backtick under "ESC"... works... did not know use before..

Comment: *You could use double quotes (") to escape the reserved keyword.* - add that `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode must be enabled for to use double-quotes. And I think that (2) is preferred (because it is not dependent by server SQL mode) and must be placed before.

Answer (score 2):

If the table name or column name is a ***keyword*** or it ***contains spaces***, and you still want to use that name, quote them between backticks '`'. So your query should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `Item Type` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    `Sales Channel` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    `Order Priority` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    `Order Date` DATE NULL,
    `Order ID` DECIMAL NULL,
    `Ship Date` DATE NULL
);
```

Try it yourself at SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0332f0

Comment: P.S.: Square brackets `[]` is the notation in MS SQL Server. That won't work with MySQL.

Comment: "Item Type" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL --- showing expecting identier... when i changed the name to "Country"... the message disappearing..????

Comment: Not sure buddy, can you share the error by editing question. Here is the link to SQL Fiddle where I put Item Type as `VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL` :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6558c1

Answer (score 1):

Fix your column names so they do not have to be escaped!  This will make all subsequent work much simpler:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    SalesID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemType VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    SalesChannel VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    OrderPriority VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    OrderDate DATE NULL,
    OrderID DECIMAL NULL,
    ShipDate DATE NULL
);
```

I recommend using the table name for the `id`.  In addition, you are using `DECIMAL` with no precision or scale.  Highly UNRECOMMENDED.  Don't depend on database defaults (do you even know what they are?).

You should also include foreign key references.  So you should have a foreign key constraint to the orders table.

Comment: i have all other things OK  except the mentioned above. Yes, sir, i changed all accordingly...thnx